# How to find the repository that git hooks are running for

Tags: python, git

I have two repositories A and B.

I have set the follow git config in repository A:

`git config core.hooksPath <path to repository B>`

The git hooks in repository B now run when I perform git commands in repository A.

From inside repository B, how do I get the path to repository A? This is because many other repositories can set this git config and so repository B will need to know which repository its running its hooks for.

Note: my hooks are written in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks

«Before Git invokes a hook, it changes its working directory to either $GIT_DIR in a bare repository or the root of the working tree in a non-bare repository. An exception are hooks triggered during a push (pre-receive, update, post-receive, post-update, push-to-checkout) which are always executed in $GIT_DIR.»

I.e., you can check `$GIT_DIR` (`os.environ['GIT_DIR']` in Python) or the current directory (`pwd` in shell, `os.getcwd()` in Python).

Comment: My `os.environ` map does not have the `GIT_DIR` key. However, `os.getcwd()` gives me the correct path to the repo for which git hooks are being run. I didn't expect this because I thought the working directory would be changed to repository B when the hooks run.

Comment: It's curious that `GIT_DIR` would be unset, but you can always use `os.environ.get('GIT_DIR', os.getcwd())` to make sure that you get a usable value. (Hm: It looks like several hooks don't bother to set it, including post-checkout and all apply-patch hooks, for instance.)

Answer (score 3):

Git sets an environment variable, `GIT_DIR`, to contain the (typically relative!) path to the Git repository from the current working directory.  Being relative, this path is only good until you change directories, so you might want to convert it to an absolute path, depending on what you are going to do in your code.

Git *uses* that environment variable to locate the Git repository directory.  If `GIT_WORK_TREE` is set, that locates the work-tree, otherwise it is the current directory or the repository is bare.  Other magic Git items, such as `GIT_INDEX_FILE`, may also be set.  It's best not to change directories without making sure that every one of these is an absolute path:

```
for name in ('GIT_INDEX_FILE', 'GIT_OBJECT_DIRECTORY', 'GIT_DIR', 'GIT_WORK_TREE'):
    val = os.environ.get(name, None)
    if val is not None and not os.path.isabs(val):
        os.environ[name] = os.path.abspath(val)
for pathspec in ('GIT_ALTERNATE_OBJECT_DIRECTORIES', 'GIT_CEILING_DIRECTORIES'):
    ...
```

(I leave the code for the latter two as an exercise, especially since one is `;`-delimited on Windows, according to [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html)).  **Edit:** The `GIT_CEILING_DIRECTORIES` is documented as already absolute, so only `GIT_ALTERNATE_OBJECT_DIRECTORIES` might need tweaking.  See the manual page's description of how each field is treated here.